# My Navbar hamburger menu component in NextJS isn't working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, nav, hamburger-menu

For context, I followed this navbar component guide https://dev.to/andrewespejo/how-to-design-a-simple-and-beautiful-navbar-using-nextjs-and-tailwindcss-26p1

As stated, I am creating a website, but the Hamburger menu, when clicked, won't drop down. I also used TailwindCSS to create responsiveness within the website, where the hamburger menu only shows within the mobile view of the website. I believe the ternary operator should be working, but I don't believe the onClick method is working.

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Navbar = () => {
const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false);
const handleClick = () => {
    setNavbar(!navbar);
    console.log("clicked");
  };
    return (
      <>
        <nav className='flex items-center flex-wrap bg-blue-400 p-3 '>
          <Link href='/'>
            <a className='inline-flex items-center p-2 mr-4 '>
              <svg
                viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                className='fill-current text-white h-8 w-8 mr-2'
              >
                <path d='M12.001 4.8c-3.2 0-5.2 1.6-6 4.8 1.2-1.6 2.6-2.2 4.2-1.8.913.228 1.565.89 2.288 1.624C13.666 10.618 15.027 12 18.001 12c3.2 0 5.2-1.6 6-4.8-1.2 1.6-2.6 2.2-4.2 1.8-.913-.228-1.565-.89-2.288-1.624C16.337 6.182 14.976 4.8 12.001 4.8zm-6 7.2c-3.2 0-5.2 1.6-6 4.8 1.2-1.6 2.6-2.2 4.2-1.8.913.228 1.565.89 2.288 1.624 1.177 1.194 2.538 2.576 5.512 2.576 3.2 0 5.2-1.6 6-4.8-1.2 1.6-2.6 2.2-4.2 1.8-.913-.228-1.565-.89-2.288-1.624C10.337 13.382 8.976 12 6.001 12z' />
              </svg>
              <span className='text-xl text-white font-bold uppercase tracking-wide'>
                Portfolio
              </span>
            </a>
          </Link>
          <button className=' inline-flex p-3 hover:bg-blue-500 rounded lg:hidden text-white ml-auto hover:text-white outline-none' onClick={handleClick}>
            <svg
              className='w-6 h-6'
              fill='none'
              stroke='currentColor'
              viewBox='0 0 24 24'
              xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
            >
              <path
                strokeLinecap='round'
                strokeLinejoin='round'
                strokeWidth={2}
                d='M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16'
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <div className={` ${
            navbar ? '' : 'hidden'
          }   w-full lg:inline-flex lg:flex-grow lg:w-auto`}>
            <div className='lg:inline-flex lg:flex-row lg:ml-auto lg:w-auto w-full lg:items-center items-start  flex flex-col lg:h-auto'>
              <Link href='/'>
                <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white '>
                  Home
                </a>
              </Link>
              <Link href='/'>
                <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white'>
                  Experience
                </a>
              </Link>
              <Link href='/about'>
                <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white'>
                  About 
                </a>
              </Link>
              <Link href='/'>
                <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white'>
                  Projects
                </a>
              </Link>
              <Link href='/'>
                <a className='lg:inline-flex lg:w-auto w-full px-3 py-2 rounded text-white font-bold items-center justify-center hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white'>
                  Contact 
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </>
    );
  };
```

`

I have tried testing the onclick function by adding test buttons but they weren't displaying on the navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving the `onclick` an anonymous function.

```
<button className='inline-flex p-3 hover:bg-blue-500 rounded lg:hidden text-white ml-auto hover:text-white outline-none' onClick={()=>handleClick()}>
```

Comment: Why does that fix it?